# Angular Component is not an element in another module

Tags: angular, storybook

I'm trying to use a component declared in one module in another module. I have added it to exports in the original module and imported that module in current one. But when I go and use the template of the component in the current components html file it says ng3004 :  is not a known element.

Consider other to be the component I want to import in current.

other.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    OtherComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [OtherComponent]
})
export class OtherModule { }
```

current.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CurrentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule, OtherModule
  ],
  exports: [CurrentComponent]
})
export class CurrentModule { }
```

current.component.html

```html
<other-component></other-component>
```

It gives the above error. I'm using Storybook to view these component btw.

Comment: has you import the CurrentModule in the main.module? (or if you're using lazy loaded in the lazy loaded module)

Comment: The code you've shown looks good. I assume you might have a typo somewhere or problems with another element. I quickly created your example in StackBlitz, see [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-afnhst?file=src/app/current/current.component.html)
Looks just like you want it, doesn't it?

Comment: Yea I don't know what the issue is. Doesn't seem to be any typo. Anyways thanks for letting me know. I can be at least sure that it's not my code causing the failure. Maybe some storybook problem.